# Drag and drop does not work with larger objects in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to write an automated test with drag and drop in it, and it should drag an item from a grid to another grid. I have run the following code with different success:

When I run this code, it will work if the object moved is just a label, but if it is a label and a textbox it will fail (or rather, the test will pass but in reality the object will not be moved)
I´m thinking that the grid maybe doesn't have time to load properly for the bigger object?:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Point point = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(destination)).Location;
Thread.Sleep(100);

builder.DragAndDropToOffset(element, point.X, point.Y).Build().Perform();
```

If I run this code it will sometimes work in debug mode with larger objects as well, but not all the time. I often get a `StaleElementReferenceExeption` on the `dragAndDrop.Perform();` when I run this.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
IAction dragAndDrop = builder.ClickAndHold(element)
 .MoveToElement(target)
 .Release(target)
 .Build();

dragAndDrop.Perform();
```

I have tested different code variations but these are the ones almost working.

Comment: I haven't used this much but I'll suggest a couple things that may or may not help... 1) use of Thread.Sleep() generally isn't a good practice and 100 is 100ms which isn't a lot of time. If absolutely necessary, maybe try more time. Better yet... is there something on the page that changes once the drop is completed? An element that changes? If so, use WebDriverWait to wait for the change and then proceed. 2) .Location returns the top left corner, have you tried dropping to the middle of the element instead?

Comment: Hi JeffC and thank you for your answer. I have tried to increase the Thread.Sleep() to 3000 but that will not work either. Yes there is something that changes on the page when the drop is compleated. An item is moved from one side of the page to the other on to a grid full of other objects who moved and gived place for the new object. I tried WebDriverWait, but I am not shure where to insert it. I would like to insert it after MoveToElement, but VisualStudio will not let me. And funny thing with the top left corner, cause the item will be inserted in the bottom. No clue why.

Comment: WebDriverWait waits for a condition to occur... element to be visible, clickable, etc. so you will want to execute the drag and drop and then use WebDriverWait. You will want to identify an element that changes properties, attributes, etc. after the drag and drop and wait on those changes to occur. Then you know the action is done and your script can progress.

Comment: Thank you JeffC. I will explore this further and get back to this thread with my findings.